# Binding dictionary values to a Combobox in Windows form

Tags: c#

Is it possible to bind dictionary values to a Windows `Combobox`?
I can only find good solutions for WPF applications

```
Dictionary<object,object>ProductInfo = new Dictionary<object, object>();

foreach (var data in p)
{
    ProductInfo.Add(data.PenType, data.PenColor);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", data.PenType,data.PenColor);
}
```

Comment: Solved it  comboname.DataSource = new BindingSource(ProductInfo, null);

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [**BindingSource Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
combobox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(ProductInfo,null); 
//ProductInfo is your dictionary
combobox1.ValueMember = "Key";
combobox1.DisplayMember= "Value";
```

Comment: I believe his own comment with the solution was posted before the answer.